# Storing clip for Pro Design Aero Bottle

Tags: accessories, storage, hydration

So I keep my bike in the garage, in Florida where there are plenty of critters.  This would include lizards and frogs including the expected insects.  Heck the other day there was a bird trapped in my garage!

As such I really don't like to keep water bottles anywhere but inside the house where the critter population is far more controlled.  I have one of these water bottles:

[image: The bottle]

There is a strap that holds it in place that without the water bottle in place, the strap would easily fall out.

Any hints on how to store the bottle and the strap so the strap does not become lost?

Comment: The picture's a little small and hard to see. Is it an [Aero HC](http://www.profile-design.com/product/hydration/aero-hc-system/)? (Even on the manufacturer's site, the strap's kinda little hard to see!)

Answer (score 2):

If the strap disconnects from the bottle holder, I would keep the strap with/inside the bottle (I would clean it first).

I had one of the older profile designs aero bottles and the always kept the yellow scrunchy with/inside the bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Without being 100% sure as the picture isn't very informative, it looks like you need to make a fake bottle.  I'd use a long strip of corrguated card cut to approximately the length of the bottle and rolled to the right diameter (you don't have to do this all with one piece).  You could start with a core from something like a roll of paper towel, and wrap the card round that.

Comment: This isn;t something to be seen on the road though -- strictly for storage only, or you'll get laughed at

Comment: being laughed at on the road just means you're riding too slow.

Comment: You might be able to find the right size on a soft drink / bottled water bottle to use.